# redirect ssl http to https issue in apache

Tags: ssl, proxy, tomcat, apache-2.4, redirection

i am a newbie with apache. need some advise regarding redirecting http to https. It looks like everything in the ssl.conf is copasetic, once i logged on to ssl environment, every links i clicked seem to want to redirect back to http, and get the error "Bad Request - Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port. Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please." below are the codes in the ssl.conf. any advise what might be causing the issues?

NOTE: 10.0.0.24:8080 is the port that planner now runs on in test environment. This is something that was changed recently, but since it is just a PROXY, not sure how it might cause the issue with just this area of the site? But open to suggestions. Thank you all in advance.

code:

```
Listen 8001
Listen 8004


<VirtualHost *:8001>
SSLEngine on
ServerName test.mydomainintereactive.com:8001
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/conf/certs/cert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/conf/certs/test.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/httpd/conf/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt"

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          etc...
#
# Security and Server protection (GLG - 2015-08)
#
    TraceEnable Off
    ServerSignature Off
    FileETag None

    CustomLog       /var/log/httpd/test-access.log combined
    ErrorLog        /var/log/httpd/test-error.log

#       ErrorDocument   400     https://test.mydomainintereactive.com:8001

    ProxyPreserveHost       On
    ProxyPass       /       http://10.0.0.24:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse        /       http://10.0.0.24:8080/
</virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:8004>
SSLEngine on
ServerName fun.mydomainintereactive.com:8004
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/conf/certs/FUN2010Cert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/conf/certs/FUN2010Key2.pem"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/httpd/conf/certs/gd_bundle.crt"

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          etc..
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on

#
# Security and Server protection (GLG - 2015-08)
#
    TraceEnable Off
    ServerSignature Off
    FileETag None

        CustomLog       /var/log/httpd/fun77-access.log combined
        ErrorLog        /var/log/httpd/fun77-error.log

#       ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.22:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.22:8080/
</virtualhost>
```

Comment: There is no redirection in your config, just proxy

Comment: Did you configure scheme, proxyName and proxyPort in your tomcat connector?

Comment: Gerald sir, thank you for your suggestion, i will check if the connector is configured and confirmed the proxy settings. should i add the redirector on my ssl.conf?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod_rewrite.c to redirect a request to https.
Though make sure you don't enable `SSLEngine` on the page you want to redirect from.

In this example I'm redirecting all traffic coming in to test.mydomainintereactive.com on port 80 to test.mydomainintereactive.com on port 443 (standard https port)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.mydomainintereactive.com
    # This it where they try to go but should be redirected from.
    # We can do this with mod_rewrite.c

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        # If you want to use another port than 443 you might have
        # to put this in the redirect on the line below.
        RewriteRule ^[^\/]*\/(.*) https://test.mydomainintereactive.com/$1 [R=301,L]
     </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.mydomainintereactive.com
    # This is the site we want to be redirected to.
    # and where you have your SSL settings.

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/conf/certs/FUN2010Cert.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/conf/certs/FUN2010Key2.pem"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/httpd/conf/certs/gd_bundle.crt"
    # ... etc.
</virtualhost>
```